# What script is this, and what does it mean?

Tags: cross-linguistic, language-identification

[image: Script on trousers]

A girl in the gym has this printed down her trousers but has no idea what the text means or where the trousers even were bought from.

My two guesses are either Amharic or Oghams. Who knows?

Comment: Did you look at samples of those scripts to see if your idea is plausible?

Comment: Well oghams was a very equivocal maybe because the letters seem to all be on one line in Wikipedia but maybe there are different conventions like Chinese script directions or Hebrew vowels etc

Comment: Looks like Futhark to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the [Medieval (Latinized) Futhark runic alphabet](https://omniglot.com/writing/runic.htm), written [*scriptio continua*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scriptio_continua), but the text is English: *THE BRAVE MAY LIVE FOREVER*